# How can I generate a random value for username in django user model?

Tags: django, database, django-models

I am satisfied with django default user model but I want the user name to be autogenerated. I don't want to create a custom user model. I need to define a function that generate unique random usernames as follows :

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=generate_username())
def generate_username():
   pass
```

I don't want to generate a random username using `random module` and then check if it exists, otherwise, create another random, check it again and so on.

**Is there a fast way to do this ?**

Comment: Do you care about the format of the username? `uuid.uuid1()` is almost guaranteed to generate unique values

Comment: uuid seems like the way to go, but Is there a way to set the username to be the same as the user id

Comment: I can't know the user id until the user is saved, and user can not be created without username.

Comment: You could make the username field the primary key so that there is no `id` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import string, random
def generate_username(length):
   username = string.ascii_lowercase #assuming you want only lowercase
   return ''.join(random.choice(username) for i in range(length))
```

Comment: psst... do you mean `username` instead of `letters` in your return statement? FYI `letters` is never defined

Comment: I don't want to do it with random module, I need a collision-free way to do it, like making the database generate it for me or setting it the same as the user id

Answer (score 0):

MeL's answer is definitely workable, but I'll recommend using this library called [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.person.html). It generates **actual** names instead of just random characters. So your code should look something like:

```py
from faker import Faker
fakegen = Faker()

def generate_username(n=5):
    for i in range(n):
        fake.first_name()    # Megan, Katherine, Robert, so on
```

There are more examples in the documentation. Linked above.

*Note* remember to run

```py
pip install faker
```

before you proceed.

**EDIT**

To make this collision-proof, I will commit these changes:

```py
from faker import Faker
fakegen = Faker()

import random

def generate_username():
    # e.g. jonathanfisher2352
    return fake.first_name().lower() + fake.last_name.lower() + random.randint(1000, 9999)
```

Comment: There is a high chance of collisions using this method

Comment: If the library's big enough I don't think the chance will be high (not mentioned in the docs though). The dumb way (since it said username) is to concatenate one name with a random number ranging from 1 to 1000 *or* with another name. If this still collides... I can't imagine how many operations are executed

Comment: I need a collision-free way. random is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I will share it once I know it

Comment: How much data do you have? If you have something less than a million, then this will have an extremely low chance of colliding. There are at least 100 first *and* last name plus a 4-digit number, so you'll have 100*100*9000 = 90 million combinations.

Comment: The point is that there will never be a collision-free way unless you do a check every time you generate a name. But then you must iterate over an array every time you generate a name and that will be extremely slow and resource-demanding.

Comment: the username field is unique, so the database won't accept duplicates anyway. I will have to check and generate new names every time and as you said that's resource-intensive. I think I will subclass django user model and remove the user name field If I didn't find a better way.

Comment: Rn I think the best solution is to do a while loop and, inside, try to find an object with the corresponding username. Keep doing this until you can't find a duplicate. As the four-digit number will be regenerated every time, two or three while loops should do the trick.

Comment: For testing you could use the "unique" feature of faker:

```python
import faker

fake = faker.Faker()

numbers = set(fake.unique.random_int() for i in range(1000))
assert len(numbers) == 1000
```

From official docs: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fakerclass.html#unique-values